# How to disable ipython prompt blinking

Tags: python, ipython

I recently downloaded the **anaconda** pkg and installed it in a redhat system with

> Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)

When I run the **ipython** prompt it always keep blinking for input lines. Is there anyway to disable this?

I would appreciate if anyone can give descriptive instructions since I'm new to this.

Regards,
Indika.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython has a notion of profiles to allow for different kinds of configurations. If this is news to you, you've probably just been using the default profile and not known it. In the shell, run the ipython profile create command to be sure (don't worry, if you alreay have a profile, this won't overwrite it). Now ipython locate profile will tell you the directory which contains all of the configuration for the default profile.

In [1]: !ipython profile create

In [2]: !ipython locate profile

/home/pi/.ipython/profile_default

In [3]: x = !ipython locate profile

In [4]: cd $x.s

/home/pi/.ipython/profile_default

In [5]: ls

There's a lot of stuff there, but we just need to add our one line to the end of the file in static/custom/custom.js

In [6]: cd static/custom/

/home/pi/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom

In [7]: ls

custom.css  custom.js

In [8]: !echo "codemirror.defaults.cursorblinkrate=0" >> custom.js

or if you say
"I want it all and I want it now!"

You say you don't want to save your current notebook and reload it to get the updated CodeMirror settings? You just want all cells in the current notebook to change their behavior? Well, OK, Freddie:

In [9]:
       %%javascript

```
   var rate = 0;
   // apply setting to  all current CodeMirror instances
   IPython.notebook.get_cells().map(
       function(c) {  return c.code_mirror.options.cursorBlinkRate=rate;  }
   );

   // make sure new CodeMirror instance also use this setting
   CodeMirror.defaults.cursorBlinkRate=rate;
```