# How to disable ipython prompt blinking?

Tags: python, ipython

When I run ipython (7.12.0, this is from the Anaconda distro) in an xterm, the In prompts blink. It's super irritating. How do I turn it off?

The only thing that blinks is the text of the input prompt "In [#]:' at the beginning of every ipython input line. Nothing else in the terminal window blinks. To be specific, I am not asking about the cursor. The cursor is not blinking.

Note, there is a previous question, [How to disable ipython prompt blinking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197990/how-to-disable-ipython-prompt-blinking), that purports to answer this exact question. However, it is out-of-date. The answer given there doesn't work. Also, I suspect the answer was meant for the jupyter notebook. I'm asking about the terminal version of ipython.

Comment: that is your terminal setting.

Comment: @Mox: I'm sorry, I don't understand. *What* are you saying is my terminal setting?

Comment: Your terminal emulator specifies how your cursor is displayed, not iPython. (Though if your cursor only blinks in iPython, then iPython may be sending some byte sequence that your terminal emulator interprets as a request to blink the cursor.)

Comment: @chepner: But this is not about my cursor. The cursor is not blinking. It is the "In [#]:" number prompt at the beginning of every ipython input line that blinks.

Comment: I gather that people ask about blinking cursors so often that it has become impossible to ask about anything else that blinks.

Comment: May I ask what is appealing about using iPython over and above Jupyter?

Comment: @Plato77: Sometimes it is quicker and easier to work in a terminal/commandline environment than a web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blinking can be is suppressed by the xterm cm option.

```
xterm +cm &
```

produces an xterm that, when ipython runs in it, has color but no blinking text.

Answer (score -1):

The blinking cursor is a feature of the terminal itself.
If you are using XTerm, you can disable the cursor:

```
setterm -cursor off
```

You can re-enable it with:

```
setterm -cursor on
```